# Unable to insert variable into string

Tags: python, string

I am little bit new to Python and I got stuck a bit in this moment:

```
c = 5
cmds.pointPosition(geo[0]+".cv[0]["+c+"2]", w=True)
```

it gives me error:

> Error: TypeError: file  line 39: coercing to Unicode:
>   need string or buffer, int found #

Question is how to put variable `c = 5` inside second bracket so it will be `7`?

Comment: Try `str(c)` or `format()` or an f-string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid string concatenation when you can. This is a good use case for [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
cmds.pointPosition("{}.cv[0][{}]".format(geo[0], c + 2), w=True)
```

Which works assuming `c` holds the value of an integer to begin with (otherwise, the `c + 2` step fails).

Comment: Awesome explanation . Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Python does not automatically convert an integer into its string representation like some languages. You need convert it explicitly yourself with `str()`, `format()`, or an f-string.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = 5
cmds.pointPosition(geo[0]+".cv[0][" + str(c) + "2]", w=True)
```

In Python, you can't concatenate str and int.